# getFileByServerRelativeURL fails when the filename contains a pound(#)

Tags: rest, office365apis

I'm using the SharePoint online REST API. Things generally work fine, but I'm failing to figure out how to get information about a file (document) that contains a pound in its name. Here's my REST call:

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl("/Shared Documents/Roys #quoted doc.txt")
```

The response I'm getting is '404 File not found', with the error being "The expression "Web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl("/Shared Documents/Roys #quoted doc.txt")"

I've tried all sorts of tricks with encoding the path (%23 encoding for the quote sign, back slashing the pound, etc.), but failed to figure out the right one.

Is there any kind of encoding I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GetFileByServerRelativePath` instead of `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl`.

```
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedUrl='file URL')
```

Ensure that any special characters in the file URL have been encoded.